# javax.management.MBeanServerFactory is a restricted class

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I'm trying to make spring boot work with GAE, however when I run `appengine:devserver` the app throws:

```
[INFO] Jun 03, 2014 11:43:26 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
[INFO] WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.management.MBeanServerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.:
[INFO] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.management.MBeanServerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils.locateMBeanServer(JmxUtils.java:106)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils.locateMBeanServer(JmxUtils.java:86)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1602)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1599)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
```

How to I work-around this issue?

Comment: It is a warning and shouldn't be fatal, I would expect it still to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed [this app](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae) yesterday to GAE (from master) and it's running fine (no sign even of the logger issue you were having). So what's the difference? I did have to make some changes to Boot master too, but never saw the class not found issues that you do.

Answer (score 0):

The line `"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.management.MBeanServerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details."` in your error message is due to the Google app engine's restriction.

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist?csw=1)

App engine doesn't allow your application to access `javax.management.*` .